# how to set equal margin space to logo,banner and content of responsive bootstrap website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a responsive website, which will have logo at left side, a banner and then the content. But the issue is logo, banner and the content left and right margin are not getting equal space.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
  content here
</div>
```

Comment: don't you have any kind of css code? its hard to imagine.

Comment: I am using bootstrap default css

Comment: Bootstrap has its own margin for components. @user1681166 Can you provide the code or a snapshot of your output so that i can figure out the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid{
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

You can write your own Styling and modify the margin according to your requirement.

Here is the sample fiddle for you
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29485/